Is this some kind of trashline orb weaver?
Is this some kind of trashline orb weaver or some other type of spider? Location is southwestern Virginia and the photo was taken in late July, in the morning.




The first two photos show the markings on the spider’s body. The color wasn’t quite preserved intact—-the spider’s body is a rust colored shade of orange, similar to the color of red clay dirt when it’s dry. The spider’s body is probably between the size of a green pea and an small garbanzo bean and is bulbous with relatively short black shiny legs. Total spider size including legs looks to be roughly nickel sized.
The web is highly complex with three key features numbered 1-3 in the last two photos. The first of these photos is front-on. The second is slightly to the side and shows that the orb web is slightly conical and how it connects to the trashline. Apologies for the photo quality, this was the best I could do with my phone’s camera. Fortunately the web was dew-laden which made the threads stand out more than normal:

The trash line (?) which is a short fat string of trash whose color and texture exactly matches that of the spider and is composed of bug shells and from what I could tell bits of clay dirt! The spider hides at the end of this structure and is perfectly camouflaged except for its front legs which it sticks out.

There’s an orb web that looks standard except for one difference that doesn’t translate well in photos: the web has a slightly conical shape, with the center of the web pulled toward the trash line and a small hole in the orb web apparently forming the opening of a tunnel to the trash line.

There’s what looks like a tunnel formed by a handful to half a dozen threads going between the orb web and the trash line. These go directly to where the spider is sitting. I’ve never seen it use the “tunnel” as a tunnel so not 100% certain that’s what it is, but that’s what it looks like structurally.


The rest of the web is a collection of chaotic random threads densely filling 3D space behind the orb web, and a few sparsely filling the space a couple of inches in front of the orb web. I’ve only ever seen these webs in the corners of fences.
The spider enlarges the web over time with the orb web gradually moving forward out from the corner, presumably being torn down and reconstructed farther and farther forward over time, so these webs can become quite large, measuring a good foot and a half or more on the side.
This is the first time I got a good view of the spider FWIW. I generally don’t view the web in the morning, and all other times of day the spider is steadfastly hiding in its trash line; this time it happened to come out and expose its body clearly. It was doing something but not sure what, maybe building on the trash line?
Any idea what type of spider this is, and what function each part of the complex web serves?
